# Yii2 is it possible to run rest action within the app itself?

Tags: rest, yii, yii2

I have created a REST project in yii2 and i have some yaml data that should be stored in the database. These are crowd data, that is authorized people can add new yaml files and our app will parse those data and store in database.

But these data might change in the future (i.e. add/delete columns) which would rely on version of the REST api (v1.0, v2.0 etc)

Thus i would like to call the appropriate rest action to do it.

I know there is the function `$controller->run()` but how do i use it to make a POST or a PUT request?

Is there any alternative to using yii httpclient?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using [Yii2 Console Commands](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html)?

Comment: how is that going to help me? How do i use console commands to make POST?

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong, you want to execute different action depending on the version of the API.

For that, you can create modules inside your frontend/backend directory and name the modules as per your versions. Whenever you have a new version create a new module and upgrade the version name. Thus you always get the proper versioning. So v1, v2.. will be modules in your project.

The good thing about this is that you can have same action name in different modules under same controller name. Thus if in version 1 you have 5 columns and the api is like `/v1/data` then you can have 7 columns in version 2 and the api can be like `/v2/data`.

For more details on modules: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html

Comment: Do you understand english?

Comment: @user2707590 Yes I do understand Englilsh. You can use `Yii::$app->runAction('new_controller/new_action', ['param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2']);` to forward the request. But, keeping separate versions of the API will help you in maintaining the code and any changes that affect the schema of the DB. Moreover you can put your common code/business logic in the models.

Comment: @user2707590 If you have found any good solution, please let the community know. We are here to help each other, not to judge.

Comment: i want to make POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE requests from my controllers.